# What superheroes have worked for the Daily Bugle in the comics?

Tags: marvel, comics

Peter Parker, aka Spider-Man, quite famously worked for the Daily Bugle. However, upon doing research for another question I found out that Carol Danvers, before she was aware that she was Ms Marvel, became the editor of Woman Magazine which was owned by the Daily Bugle as we see in *Ms Marvel Vol. 1* Issue 1.

[image: Page from the aforementioned comic showing Carol being tasked with writing an expose on Ms Marvel]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Have any other superheroes worked for the Daily Bugle in the comics?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like there are more than I thought there would be. From my looking around it appears there are at least 8 others and possibly more.

#### Thomas Fireheart aka Puma

In *The Spectacular Spider-Man Vol. 1* Issue 156 Thomas buys 51% of the Daily Bugle shares and became the new owner so he could positively promote Spider-Man.

[image: Page from the comic with JJJ being upset and introducing Puma as the new owner]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

#### Jessica Jones

Jessica worked for the Daily Bugle twice as far as I can tell. Initially she was hired by JJJ to discover the true identify of Spider-Man before being fired. She was then also hired as part of The Pulse in secret in a research capacity before she eventually quits.

#### Jeffrey Mace aka Patriot/Captain America

*Captain America: Patriot* shows that Jeffrey was originally a reporter for the Daily Bugle.

[image: Mace being berated because he is a reporter not Captain America's sidekick]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

#### Mary Morgan aka Miss Patriot

Mary is again a reporter for the Daily Bugle and is actually the woman in the red dress in the image above.

#### Richard Jones aka Phantom Reporter

Richard is offered a job as a reporter for the Daily Bugle, we see this in *The Twelve* Issue 3.

[image: Jones is offered a job]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

#### Ethan Edwards aka Virtue

Ethan is mentioned as the new star reporter for the Daily Bugle having landed the job shortly after moving to New York as shown in *Marvel Knights Spider-Man Vol. 1* Issue 13.

[image: JJJ introduces Ethan to Peter]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

#### Phillip Urich aka Goblin King - the Good Goblin

Phil was an intern at the Daily Bugle as we see in *Green Goblin Vol. 1* Issue 1.

[image: Page showing Phil as an intern]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

#### Peter Ross aka Spider-Boy of Earth-9602

Peter was a photographer for the Daily Bugle much like his genetic father Peter Parker who he was cloned from as we see in *Spider-Boy Vol. 1* Issue 1.

[image: Peter stating he is a photographer for the Daily Bugle]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

---

I'm hesitant to add her here because Mystique isn't really a hero, more a villain, but she has worked as a hero at times but was still more of an anti-hero. However, she did work for the Daily Bugle as she mentions in *X-Factor Vol. 1* Issue 139.

[image: Mystique recounting her time as a reporter for the Daily Bugle]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Answer (score 10):

A likely partial list based off of names I recognize from [here](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Daily_Bugle_(The_DB!)_members) and [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daily_Bugle) (I've avoided outright villains or those who are barely seen after their reformation):

- [Phillip Urich](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Phillip_Urich_(Earth-616)) (aka the Good Goblin)
- [Richard Jones](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Richard_Jones_(Phantom_Reporter)_(Earth-616)) (aka The Phantom Reporter)
- [Jessica Jones](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Jessica_Jones_(Earth-616))
- [Peter Parker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man) (aka Spider-Man)
- [Carol Danvers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carol_Danvers) (aka Ms. Marvel)
- [Mary Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Comics_characters:_M#Miss_Patriot) (aka Miss Patriot)
- [Jeffrey Mace](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/patriot/4005-44588/) (aka Patriot)
- [Raven Darkholme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystique_(comics)) (aka Mystique, as Randy Green)
- [Thomas Fireheart](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/puma/4005-15238/) (aka Puma)
- [Peter Ross](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/spider-boy/4005-46768/) (aka Spider-Boy)

Comment: Isn't Mystique a villain?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: Much like Venom and Phil Urich, they've gone back and forth.

Comment: Venom is certainly an anti-hero/villain but I can't remember Mystique being a hero at all. Maybe I'll have to look some more.

Comment: The only one I have found that you haven't is Ethan Edwards. We have the same amount though because I haven't included Mystique yet,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100927/discussion-between-fuzzyboots-and-thelethalcarrot).